# Include HttpCalloutMock in TestSetup

Tags: apex, unit-test, httpcalloutmock

I am writing a testclass that has to perform a callout. 
The callout returns a JSON string that is used to update a custom object in salesforce. This custom object has a master-detail relationship with the Account object.

This is my test data setup method.

```
@testSetup static void setupdata()
{
    // Create Account Record  
    Account myaccount            =  new Account();
    myaccount.Name               = 'Test Account';
    insert myaccount;

//Create collection records 200 to testbatch
   List<Customer_Collection__C> mylist = new List<Customer_Collection__c>();
   for(Integer i=0;i<200;i++)
   {
       //Create 2000 customer collection records.
       Customer_collection__c ccc = new Customer_collection__c();
       ccc.Account__c = myaccount.Id; //This is the value that I need to be in the Mock
       ccc.Flow_Update_Date__c = Date.today() -10;
       ccc.TotalAmountOverDue__c = 2011.00;
       mylist.Add(ccc);
   }
   insert mylist;
}
```

This is my mock.

```
 @isTest
    global class MockOverDue implements HttpCalloutMock 
    {
        global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) 
        {
            // Create a fake response
            HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.setBody('{"CollectionsDto":[{"SfdcAccount": "<AccountId>","TotalAmountOverDue": 1090.77}],"ErrorMessage": null, "ResultValue": "success" }');
            res.setStatusCode(200);
            return res;
        }
    }
```

I am trying to get the Id of the account record created to be a part of the JSON string returned by the Mock. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: you can introduce to yourself constructor with parameters. For example, you generate test data, save ids, add constructor into MockOverDue that takes list of ids (or whatever) and use those in respond method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass it in as a parameter of your mock. Personally I find it easier to set up a class structure to serialize into/out of, so I would do something like:

```
@IsTest
public class MyMock
{
    final Id accountId;
    public MyMock(Id accountId) { this.accountId = accountId; }
    public HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest request)
    {
        HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
        response.setBody(JSON.serialize(new Response(accountId));
        // other properties
        return response;
    }
    class Response
    {
        final List<DTO> CollectionsDto;
        final String ErrorMessage, ResultValue = 'success';
        Response(Id accountId)
        {
            collectionsDto = new List<DTO> { new DTO(accountId) };
        }
    }
    class DTO
    {
        final Id SfdcAccount;
        final Double TotalAmountOverdue = 1090.77;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To (hopefully) complement Adrian's answer, note that you will have to query to get the Account Id. I also suggest keeping the mock within the test class as it usually ends up tightly coupled to the test methods.

So:

```
@IsTest
private class MyTest {

    private class Mock implements HttpCalloutMock {
        Id accountId;
        Mock(Id accountId) {
            this.accountId = accountId;
        }
        public HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest request) {
            // See Adrian's approach
        }
    }

    @TestSetup
    static void setupData() {
        ...
    }

    @IsTest
    static void myTest() {
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new Mock([select Id from Account].Id));
        Test.startTest();
        // Make request
        Test.stopTest();
        // Assert results
    }
}
```